# How to integrate NativeScript Angular android mobile application with Okta Auth flow ith PKCE

Tags: angular2-nativescript, okta, openid-connect, pkce

I have a NativeScript Angular android app, which i need to integrate with Okta. I was able to successfully integrate my Angular web application with Okta but (As i am not mobile app developer) finding it hard to wrap my mind on how to integrate it with mobile app.
I tried to go through the documentation available at Okta official site(https://developer.okta.com/docs/concepts/auth-overview/#choosing-an-oauth-2-0-flow) it feels like the recommendation is to implement Authorization Code with PKCE for which I would need below:

1.An embedded browser in the mobile app to show Okta login page.
2.Some sort of local server which can receive callback from Okta with auth code and integration of the auth code received in callback with application api service.

Do you think it is right line of thinking?

If yes, how shall i get a web server in mobile app and what would be its address(Would it be localhost?) to receive callback from Okta?

Is there any JavaScript library which can be easily integrated with NativeScript code to do it?

I came across https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-JS but not sure how can i integrate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Okta widget](https://developer.okta.com/code/javascript/okta_sign-in_widget/) and the *openAuth* method of **InAppBrowser** plugin to be able to authenticate the users and later redirect to the app again by using **deep linking**, you can see the *example* folder of that plugin: https://github.com/proyecto26/nativescript-inappbrowser#usage

We're using this plugin from React Native too and we can get the token from okta after redirect the users through deep linking, it works very well. It's required to deploy the Okta widget in an external domain and register the deep links of your apps (Android/iOS) from Okta, e.g:

- `${scheme}://${host}/callback` (Android)
- `${scheme}://callback` (iOS)